# Any simple built-in way to protect against xss in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, xss

I've got a news-feed style field which admins can edit that will appear on users' pages. All users and all admins are approved so this is a pretty low-security affair.

Is there a simple, built-in way to validate their input for malicious script injection?

Comment: Do you only want to allow them to post plain text? In that case you only need to worry about doing your HTML-escaping correctly (`<%: ... %>` et al). Or are you looking to allow 'safe' URL constructs? In that case you need an HTML purifier library, a much more complicated proposition.

Comment: @bobince I would settle for stripping out or escaping all html. I would prefer to allow simple html - <b> <a>, <ul>, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Web Protection Library: http://wpl.codeplex.com/

It's not built-in, but it's highly regarded and built for ASP.NET

Comment: Lack of documentation is not encouraging and those reviews are...also less than so. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is anything out there that is both simple and mature - at the moment. You can give [OWASP Enterprise Security API](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI) a try, but you'll unlikely be any happier than with [WPL](http://wpl.codeplex.com/).

I'd recommend adhering to the [OWASP XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) guidelines, but I suspect you're already familiar.